# Flutter - Jitsi Meet I want to add new options or at least modify an option

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to add new option like invite more people not by link but with a call notification.
anyone solved this issue ?? please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use feature flages like below

```
 Map<FeatureFlag, Object> featureFlags = {
    FeatureFlag.isMeetingNameEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isServerUrlChangeEnabled: true,
    FeatureFlag.isChatEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isAddPeopleEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.areSecurityOptionsEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isCalendarEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isCloseCaptionsEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isFilmstripEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isHelpButtonEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isInviteEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isLiveStreamingEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isLobbyModeEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isOverflowMenuEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isReactionsEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isRaiseHandEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isRecordingEnabled: false,
    FeatureFlag.isReplaceParticipantEnabled: false,
  };


var options = JitsiMeetingOptions(
      isVideoMuted: true,
      roomNameOrUrl: name,
      userDisplayName: prefs.getString('username')!,
      serverUrl: 'https://**********',
      featureFlags: featureFlags,
    );
```